# How is that distance between images calculated?

Tags: image-processing, image

The command

```
ImageDistance[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.01}], 
Plot[x^2 + 0.01, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.01}]]
```

produces `33.3253`. Unfortunately, the Mathematica help to `ImageDistance` says nothing how the distance is calculated. The images are very similar.

Comment: The documentation for `ImageDistance`'s "Details and Options" says that `EuclideanDistance` is the default. You can give a different `DistanceFunction` as an option.

Comment: Yes, but what is it? Which formulas are applied to this end?

Comment: Down vote should be based.

Comment: @user64494 I cast a downvote because, in my opinion, yours is not a question, but an observation. I am not sure what you would consider an acceptable answer, short of providing documentation that is currently not available to us. Perhaps it would be more useful to bring this issue up with Wolfram Support, if your goal is to have better documentation. Additionally, this may turn out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. you are asking about your perceived solution of a problem, rather than about the issue itself that you are having.

Comment: @MarkoB: My question was inspired by a too poor Mathematica documentation to ImageDistance, where I didn't find an answer. I followed your advice concerning Wolfram Support.

Comment: If your arguments are `Graphics`, then I believe `ImageDistance` is doing the following: `id[i1_,i2_]:=EuclideanDistance[ 
Flatten @ ImageData @RemoveAlphaChannel[Image[i1],Black], 
Flatten @ ImageData @RemoveAlphaChannel[Image[i2],Black]
]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for `ImageDistance`'s "Details and Options" says that `EuclideanDistance` is the default. You can give a different `DistanceFunction` as an option.

You can replicate what `ImageDistance` is doing by default like so:

```
i1 = Rasterize@Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.01}];
i2 = Rasterize@Plot[x^2 + 0.01, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.01}];
```

Then,

```
ImageDistance[i1, i2]
```

> `25.6833`

```
EuclideanDistance[Flatten@ImageData@i1, Flatten@ImageData@i2]
```

> `25.6833`

We can do the same with other distance functions, for example:

```
ImageDistance[i1, i2, DistanceFunction -> CorrelationDistance]
```

> `0.245972`

```
CorrelationDistance[Flatten@ImageData@i1, Flatten@ImageData@i2]
```

> `0.245972`